# How to programmatically check that the proxy server is alive or not in Java

Tags: java, http, httpclient, proxy-server

How to programmatically in Java check whether a proxy server is alive or works and can be used? I mean I can use this proxy in order to access external services via this proxy.

For instance, setting up an Authenticated Proxy with code like this:

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(proxyHostNameOrIp, 8282),   
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
```

what if 'username' and 'password' were entered by the user (and entered incorrectly)?   Is there any mechanism to 'validate' that the proxy information is valid assuming it has all been entered by a user?

Comment: Can you explain what have you tried so far? And what do you mean by "not blocked in google"?

Comment: @m0skit0, right now I have no idea where I should go with this. I need your suggestion or code samples in order to implement it.

Comment: What kind of proxy are you talking about? Web? SOCKS? Other?

Comment: @fge, I think web proxy

Comment: Well, in pure Java, you have no choice but to try and open a "real" connection since you have no nmap...

Comment: @fge, thanks. How about socks proxy ?

Comment: No idea since I've never had to deal with one :p

Comment: Either you just ask google to provide you with an answer to your question or you need to try.  Any reason you have this particular problem?

Comment: FYI: I edited this posted rather than entering a new question as I believe I understood the intent of the original question - I found this question via searching for the same one.  Thus, I took out the specifics of 'google' and added specifics about how to know if the settings one uses can be validated in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion in order to achieve this you have to check your proxy server is alive or not by using following piece of code.

If boolean variable conectionStatus is true your server is alive.

```
public boolean testConnection() {
  boolean connectionStatus=false;

  try {
      InetAddress addr=InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8");//here type proxy server ip      


      connectionStatus=addr.isReachable(1000); // 1 second time for response

  }                               
  catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println(e.toString());
  }

  return connectionStatus;
}
```

Comment: This will check, that one network-wise can reach the proxy server on IP 8.8.8.8 - but not that the proxy server will allow one to reach e.g. google.com.

Comment: The job of proxy server is to fetch the web page for its client. If for example www.google.com is not blocked on proxy server then definitely it will fetch the web page for its client. We just have to check proxy server is alive or not

Comment: Ok, but what if my proxy server has an authenticated user and password and what about if it uses a different port.

Comment: How to check if it needs to authentication ?